# Is there any shortcut keys to open nautilus

Tags: nautilus, keyboard, shortcut-keys

By <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> I can open terminal. So Is there any keyswitch to open nautilus? or we should define that?

Comment: @castigate You can try <Super(Win)key+1> as by default nautilus has dash 1 place.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default there is none, but you can set one:

```
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom shortcut
```

Then press the `+` Button. The command to run is `nautilus`.

After creating the shortcut, click 'disabled' then press the desired key combination (*e.g.*, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) to set the new shortcut.

Comment: I chose Super+N (N for nautilus).

Comment: `Super + E` somewhat reflect Windows shortcut to Explorer (`Windows + E`)

Comment: It's the same as in Windows. Which is why I choose it because I was already used to it from Windows.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> opens Nautilus, at least in the default Ubuntu + Unity installation.

Comment: in Unity 7.2 it will move to an already opened Nautilus window if any, and won't open a new window

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.10, this shortcut launches the first item on the Ubuntu dash, which may or may not be GNOME Files (AKA Nautilus). (For me, that’s Mozilla Firefox.)

Answer (score 5):

If you're coming from Windows and are used to `Win + E` for opening explorer, I'd suggest following the steps below to achieve the same effect. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 although this should work for earlier versions (correct me if I'm wrong).

1. Press `Win` key and search for 'Keyboard' and open up the result that comes first which is related to Keyboard Settings.
2. Scroll down and click the **+** button to add a new shortcut.
3. Give a name like 'Open Files' and for the Command field, give `nautilus -w`.
4. Click *Set Shortcut* and press Windows Key and 'E' together to bind the combo
5. Click *Add*

Now, whenever you press `Win + E`, you get a new window of the Ubuntu file explorer.

Comment: The "-w" was the missing piece of the puzzle I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> = Trash, it uses nautilus to show you the Trash! Works fine for me.

Comment: This shortcut doesn’t do anything in my testing of a modern Ubuntu build (19.10).

Answer (score 0):

**Super+1** works great. This is what I was looking for.

creating own / custom shortcut using

**nautilus .**

or

**nautilus ~/** (for home directory)

just opens up search function. While this the way to open nautilus through command line / terminal, but doesn't work out of it!